# How to use multiple reusable TableViewCells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I like to add multiple reusable UITableViewCells to a TableView. I am using this code to do this, but it won't work, it only shows the first cell.

Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        static NSString *costumeCell1 = @"Cell1";

        AppDetailCell1 *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:costumeCell1];

        if (!cell1) {
            cell1 = [[AppDetailCell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:costumeCell1];
        }

        return cell1;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {

        static NSString *costumeCell2 = @"Cell2";

        AppDetailCell2 *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:costumeCell2];

        if (!cell2) {
            cell2 = [[AppDetailCell2 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:costumeCell2];
        }

        return cell2;
    } else {

        return nil;

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of returning nil, i suggest logging an error and/or raising an exception. Also, instead of if/else/else, a `switch` would be my weapon of choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the reuse identifiers properly, you should change this code part

> AppDetailCell1 *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:costumeCell1];

```
    if (!cell1) {
        cell1 = [[AppDetailCell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:costumeCell1];
    }
```

with this

```
AppDetailCell1 *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:costumeCell1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

There is no need `if(!cell1)`, because `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: forIndexPath:` method never returns nil, as I said before that properly reuse identifier set is important.